# Query only elements which meets criteria

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
id | packageName   | app | timestamp
------------------------------------
1  | io.kodular... | A   | 111
2  | io.kodular... | B   | 222
3  | io.kodular... | A   | 444
4  | io.kodular... | C   | 555
```

How can I select elements **grouped by `app`** that have a timestamp higher than `333`, but they don't have any record lower than that number?

I need to get only `app C`, as `app A` has a lower timestamp record than 333. I have tried the following query, but it returns both `app A` and `app C`:

```
SELECT app FROM table WHERE timestamp>=333 AND NOT timestamp<333 GROUP BY app;
```

Any idea how can I perform that query?

Comment: you have also  A   | 444   ????

Comment: If there is app='D' with timestamp=333, do you want it returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT app
FROM table t
GROUP BY app
HAVING MIN(timestamp) >= 333 ;
```

Comment: I think it needs `...AND MAX(timestamp) > 333`.

Comment: @forpas . . . If the `MIN()` is greater than or equal to than 333, then so is the `MAX()`.

Comment: The requirement is `...that have a timestamp higher than 333`. So if there is only 1 timestamp = 333 then this `app` should not be returned.

Comment: Yes, but if this minimum is the only timestamp and it is 333 then it should not be returned.

Comment: @forpas "How can I select elements grouped by app that have a timestamp higher than 333, but they don't have any record lower than that number?" Yes you are actually right, it should be `>` and not `>=`

Comment: @DavidAlvarez no. It should be: `MIN(timestamp) >= 333 AND MAX(timestamp) > 333`.

Comment: No because then you allow a group which has it's min timestamp to 333 and it should be **higher than 333**. And then if the min is > 333, then no need to have a max condition

Comment: A group with min timestamp = 333 and a higher timestamp should be allowed.

Comment: @forpas Where do you see it ? He wrote : **"How can I select elements grouped by app that have a timestamp higher than 333, but they don't have any record lower than that number?"**

Comment: So when I read *than that number* I suppose it means 333, or not?

Comment: @forpas `> : higher than` and `>= : higher than or equal`

Comment: This solution worked as it should! Thank you! It returns only app C